# Using Universal Image Loader with Fragments gives errors when referring to base activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I'm using the Universal Image Loader from nostra13 at https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader. My problem is:

I have these classes

`PhotoActivity extends FragmentActivity`

`ImageFragment extends Fragment`

I initialize the `imageLoader` in the `ImageFragment` using `imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();` and in this fragment, I also display a few images using `imageLoader.displayImage(...)`.

When my `PhotoActivity` gets stopped (`onStop()` is called), my `ImageFragment` stops as well and this should stop any image loading because I call `imageLoader.stop()` in the `onStop()` method. However, this is not the case and it gives me NullPointerException because `onLoadingComplete()` of `ImageLoadingListener()` is called afterwards, and this method calls `getActivity()` which is `null` at this point because the fragment was detached from its activity.

`imageLoader.stop()` should stop every loading process, no?

Comment: could somebody with higher reputation than 1500 please tag this question with universal-image-loader because it's a new tag and i can't do it.

Comment: Obviously enough it doesn't stop them.

Comment: for now, i'm using using a `if(getActivity() != null)` check to prevent this error, although it would be nice if it was solved by just `imageLoader.stop()`. i'm asking to find out if i'm using the library correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageLoader use `ExecutorService` as pool for tasks. ImageLoader.stop() just do ExecutorService.shutdown() which has next Java docs:

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>
> This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution.

There is no guaranty that active tasks will be shutdown immediately after `shutdown()`. Maybe using of `shutdownNow()` is better option for that case (I'll think about it), but it still can't give you a guarantee of immediately task shutdown.

So at this moment anyway you should check `getActivity()`. But I'll think about preventing firing of callbacks after ImageLoader has stopped. Maybe in the next version.